# Java NIO server Selector loop

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, socket, tcp

I have a server that uses Java NIO in non-blocking mode. Right now I'm using a single thread for the selector, and four worker threads to process the `bytes` after the selector reads them in. I'm going to switch to a thread pool soon enough. Anyway, that's not why I'm here.

Take a look at the code below. I have a state object of type `CommunicationStatus` called `commsState` which maintains various parameters relating to the `SocketChannel`, the number of bytes read, the current working state, whether the message is complete or not, the `ByteBuffer` for that particular `SocketChannel`, etc. This works well. The `CommunicationStatus` object is attached to the `SelectionKey` when the `SocketChannel` is registered with the `Selector`.

When I'm checking `key.readyOps()` to check what state the channel is in, I have an additional check within the `OP_READ` and `OP_WRITE` checks to make sure that the worker threads have finished processing the work before additional bytes are read from or written to the `SocketChannel`.
So for example, `if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ)` returns `true` but `if (commsState.getCurrentState() == CommunicationStatus.STATE_READ)` returns `false` then no bytes will be read at this time.
I find this works really well, but is it the correct way to do things? 
Is there a better way I could handle this?
Any other comments or thoughts are appreciated too.

```
private boolean running;
private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort));

        log.info("Selector Thread: FirmwareServer " + FirmwareServer.SERVER_VERSION
                + " Runnable- Listening for connections on port: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        running = true;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SelectionKey serverAcceptKey = serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (running) {

            try {

                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

                while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keyIterator.next();
                    keyIterator.remove();

                    if (!key.isValid()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    CommunicationStatus commsState = (CommunicationStatus) key.attachment();

                    if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) == SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

                        acceptConnection(selector, key);

                    } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {

                        if (commsState.getCurrentState() == CommunicationStatus.STATE_READ) {

                            commsState.setSelectionKey(key);
                            readFromSocketChannel(key);

                        }
                    } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) == SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) {

                        if (commsState.getCurrentState() == CommunicationStatus.STATE_WRITE) {

                            commsState.setSelectionKey(key);
                            writeToSocketChannel(key);

                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Selector IOException Occurred", e);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        log.error("Firmware Selector Thread: An IOException occurred", e);
        System.exit(-1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keyIterator.next();
```

This cast here is not needed; you already know that you're going to get `SelectionKey` out of the keyiterator.

Looking up a bit, you declare `Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();`, but only use it for the iterator. The variable name doesn't add anything to understanding the code, and you might just want to say `Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();`

---

```
(key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) == SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT
```

This sort of statement, I'd wrap in a function. Bit manipulation tends to be very low level stuff and looks out of place in a function responsible for doing high level stuff.

Comment: OK thanks! But there is nothing inherently wrong with the state checks within the additional checks before reading from / writing to the socket?

Comment: @bot_bot That I don't know, I don't know enough about NIO. It doesn't look wrong, though.